# Trying to solve a palindrome using integer arrays

Tags: java, arrays, palindrome

I am writing a program that would help me find whether the number entered is a palindrome or not but i am trying it using arrays. And i would like to know if that is even possible?? And if it is possible then what am i doing wrong.

I have marked the code where i think the problem lies but feel free to suggest anything.!!!!

Thanks!!!

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class palindrome
{
 public static void main(String args[])
 {
    int size = 10,i,j,flag=0;
    int num[] = new int[size];

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the size of the number ");
            size = sc.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Enter the number ");
    for(i=0;i<size;i++)
    {
        num[i]=sc.nextInt();
    }
    i=size-1;
    for(j=0;j<(size/2);j++,i--)
    {
        if(i>(size/2))
        {
                        if(num[i]==num[j])   
            {
                flag = 1;
            }
        }
    }
    if(flag==1)
    {
        System.out.println("The number is a palindrome");

    }
    else
        System.out.println("The number is not a palindrome ");
 }
}
```

Edit: Guys the problem is actually solved because i was doing a blunder mistake i.e. i was asking the user to enter the number in the form of an arry but i was not actually entering the digits in the number one by one instead i was entering the whole number in the first iteration.

But still a lot of thanks for the replies. I would still try your ideas and let you guys know. Thanks

:)

Comment: what your code currently does, is checking if the first and the last number are equal and flag it as palindrom. You should rather check if they are not equal, and go from flag 1 to flag 0

Comment: System.out.println("Enter the size of the number "); should it not be System.out.println("Enter the number : "); size is fixed to 10?

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
public boolean isPalindrome(int[] num){
    for(int i = 0 ; i < num.length/2 ; i++) {
        if(num[i]!=num[num.length-(i+1)]) return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Although my problem is solved but i will do try this as well.. This will add up to my knowledge. Thanks!!!

Comment: @Dmitry Bychenko has the same solution but with more user input verification and verbosity, so you should look at his reply.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it's *possible*, moreover, it's possible by using `ArrayList`, `String` - *whatever you like*. In order to write down a correct implementation, first *decompose your current solution*:

```
  // Extract a method, do not cram all code into main()
  // note: all you need is array, to get size of the array, put value.length
  private static boolean isPalindrome(int[] value) {
    ...
  }

  public static void main(String args[]) {
    int userInput[];
    ...

    if (isPalindrome(userInput)) {
      System.out.println("The number is a palindrome");
    }
    else {
      System.out.println("The number is not a palindrome");
    }
  }
```

Now, let's implement `isPalindrome()`:

```
  private static boolean isPalindrome(int[] value) {
    if (null == value)
      return true; //TODO: or false, or throw exception

    for (int i = 0; i < value.length / 2; ++i)
      if (value[i] != value[value.length - 1 - i])
        return false;

    return true;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest and most intuitive way (imo) to check for palindromes is through recursion. The idea is simple:

Is the first and last char the same?
**YES** Remove first and last char and check first and last char of the new `String`
**NO** There is no palindrome.

When the input is only 1 `char` then it's trivial.

Have a look at this code:

```
private void isPalindrome(String number){
    if(number.length() == 1){
        System.out.println("yes");
    }else if(number.charAt(0) == number.charAt(number.length()-1)){
        isPalindrome(number.substring(1, number.length()-1));
    }else{
        System.out.println("no");
    }
}
```

Testing with:

`isPalindrome(String.valueOf(232))` Returns `"yes"` 
`isPalindrome(String.valueOf(23))` Return `"no"`

Of course this also works with `Array`s just as easily. Replace the parameter with an array and search through the indices the same way. When cutting down the array just create a new smaller array without first and last index of the previous array.

Answer (score 0):

Your class has several issues:

- First you're not checking if a number is a palindrome or not. Your algorithm is flawed
- Second, you're asking to enter a size but in the end, the user inputs it but you don't use it yourself. Instead, you're using that introduced value in the number array.

Here's how you should do it.

```
public class Palindrome {

  private static boolean isPalindrome(int[] array) {
    for (int i = 0, j = array.length-1; i < j; i++, j--) {
      if (array[i] != array[j]) {
        return false;
      }
    }
    return true;
  }

  public static void main(String args[]) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("How many numbers do you want to enter? ");
    int size = scanner.nextInt();
    int[] numbers = new int[size];
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
      System.out.printf("Enter number %s: ", i+1);
      numbers[i] = scanner.nextInt();
    }
    if (isPalindrome(numbers)) {
      System.out.println("The number is a palindrome");
    } else {
      System.out.println("The number is not a palindrome");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot man.. Really you are right!!! Now i realize what i was doing wrong. Thank you so much!!!